# Sitecore Workflow Content Manager "Approve Button" Disabled

Tags: sitecore, workflow

I have created a content approval workflow with 3 States: Draft, Awaiting Approval & Approved.
Once the content editor completes their changes they submit the request and the item goes to awaiting approval state.
When the content manager/approver logs in to Sitecore, in the workbox they can see the option to approve the changes.
But when viewing the item from content editor the "Approve" and "Reject" button is disabled.
After editing the item these buttons become enabled.
[View for Content Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEb60.png)
Please suggest why the "Approve" and "Reject" buttons are not enabled when the Content Manager views the item.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically due to access rights. Besides write access to the item itself, and "Language Write" access on the current language, the user also needs the "Workflow Command Execute" access right on the command ("Approve" and/or "Reject" in your example). The user also needs "Workflow State Write" access right on the workflow itself.

I've found it best to create workflow roles, such as "Workflow Author", "Workflow Approver" and so on, and assign those roles to the users accordingly. Those roles can then be assigned to the workflow states (`/sitecore/system/Workflows/MyWorkflow/MyWorkflowState`) and workflow commands (`/sitecore/system/Workflows/MyWorkflow/MyWorkflowState/MyWorkflowCommand`) accordingly

It could also be due to item locking. If lock is required for editing (a Sitecore setting) and someone else has a lock on the item, the item cannot be transitioned into another state.